# Responding back from tcp server to browser

Tags: html, sockets, firefox, browser, tcp

I have a tcp server (code in C) which is in listening state, now I am trying to make a connection to it from my browser (firefox) without any API and after connecting tcp server will send back some html code, which I want the browser to decode and display as a webpage.

When I keep the tcp server in listening state and type the below url in the browser I get a connection accepted message [url say 000.000.0.0:6859] did check by entering other port numbers didn't get connection accepted message. Can someone please explain what's happening here ? What am I missing ?

```
char m[1024]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-length: %ld\r\n Content-Type: text/html\r\n <html><body> <h1>Hello world </h1></body></html>"; 

send(client_sock,m,strlen(m),0);
```

Also, I need help with:

1. Sending connection request to tcp server (which is in listening state) from the browser.
2. Want the browser to receive, decode and display a webpage.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting spaces in front of each HTTP header name? They don't belong there.

More importantly, you are missing a second required `\r\n` between the `Content-Type` header and the HTML.  HTTP headers are separated from the HTTP body by **2** `\r\n` pairs, but you are only sending **1**.

Also, you are not populating the `Content-Length` header with a valid byte count for the HTML.  You are literally sending `%ld` to the browser.

Try something more like this instead:

```
const char *fmt = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                  "Content-length: %ld\r\n"
                  "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                  "\r\n"
                  "%s"; 

const char *data = "<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>";
int datasize = strlen(data);

char m[1024];
sprintf(m, fmt, datasize, data);

send(client_sock, m, strlen(m), 0);
```

Alternatively:

```
int sendStr(int sock, const char *s)
{
    return send(sock, s, strlen(s), 0);
}

...

const char *data = "<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>";
int datasize = strlen(data);

char clbuf[32];
sprintf(clbuf, "Content-length: %ld\r\n", datasize);

sendStr(client_sock, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
sendStr(client_sock, clbuf);
sendStr(client_sock, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
sendStr(client_sock, "\r\n");         
send(client_sock, data, datasize, 0);
```

Alternatively:

```
int sendStr(int sock, const char *s)
{
    return send(sock, s, strlen(s), 0);
}

int sendStrFmt(int sock, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
    if (size > 0) {
        char *buf = malloc(size+1);
        if (buf) {
            vsnprintf(buf, size+1, fmt, args);
            result = send(sock, buf, size, 0);
            free(buf);
        } else {
            result = -1;
        }
    }
    else if (size == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        result = -1;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

...

const char *data = "<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>";
int datasize = strlen(data);

sendStr(client_sock, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
sendStrFmt(client_sock, "Content-length: %ld\r\n", datasize);
sendStr(client_sock, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
sendStr(client_sock, "\r\n"); 
send(client_sock, data, datasize, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the help! It does work. I was not aware of the format hence the space in front of each HTTP header name, lesson learnt now.

Comment: I have one more doubt. I passed a form from the tcp server and was able to view in the browser, on clicking Submit button the data gets passed to my tcp server, which now is receiving the data in 'client_message' [char client_message[2000];] variable of char datatype as below :

Comment: POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: IP:Portno
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://IP:PORTNO/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 59

name=Adam&age=40&addr=No.+10&Location=Bangalore&gender=Male

Comment: I don't want all the information, just the information after the content-length
(ie) Mainly the form data to be received in the tcp server.  Also what is the datatype of the info received at the server end [ because i try printing client_message[10] and get segmentation fault ]. Please help

Comment: @Deelight read the [HTTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). You MUST follow the HTTP protocol in order to receive requests from web clients correctly. Also read the [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) and [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html) specs on how Forms are formatted and submitted to servers.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Remy